# OpenPGP Decryption of File Stream bytes

Tags: go, openpgp

Is there a way to decrypt a large file as streams using OpenPGP and Golang?

I am having a gziped CSV file with gpg encryption.

Comment: I am not familiar with OpenPGP, but with a quick search I found https://github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp. It seems easy to work with and its still maintained.

Comment: Yes. My point is like how can i use it for decryption of a large file as streams.

Comment: Check 
https://github.com/ProtonMail/gopenpgp/blob/16358e82ba242b144dc6ff307502fd4199e41a4f/crypto/keyring_streaming.go#L188

Answer (score 0):

The Go Docs shows a package that handles the manipulation of OpenPGP messages [here](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp). Hopefully, you'll find something in there. I also found some code related to OpenPGP decryption using Go right [here](https://gist.github.com/stuart-warren/93750a142d3de4e8fdd2) so maybe this could come in handy as well.

Comment: This package is unmaintained except for security fixes. New applications should consider a more focused, modern alternative to OpenPGP for their specific task. If you are required to interoperate with OpenPGP systems and need a maintained package, consider a community fork. See https://golang.org/issue/44226.